# How can you determine all of the places AWS access key values are used in a project in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, properties-file

I have some project which uses a `system.properties` file to read values in. Currently it also stores the `aws.secretKey` and `aws.accessKeyId`. We are thinking about switching over to using a role-based authentication method. In order to do so we want to determine how much effort this will be.

Since different AWS components use these values "under the hood" how can we determine where all of these instances occur? With any other system.properties values we could simply search for the property key to find them access with System.getProperty. This doesn't work for these values.

One possibility is to remove these values and see what fails, but I'm assuming this will make me run into instance after instance and take way too long for my purposes.

Comment: Have you looked in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)? You can just switch your auth method without breaking your code. See [more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider.html)

Comment: I did but I misunderstood that before! That's amazing, thank you!

Comment: I'll post as the answer, please mark it to help another users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS SDK uses a generic implementation type, this means that you dont need to change your code, just change the **way** that you provide your credentials:

> Returns AWSCredentials which the caller can use to authorize an AWS request. **Each implementation of AWSCredentialsProvider can chose its own strategy for loading credentials.** For example, an implementation might load credentials from an existing key management system, or load new credentials when credentials are rotated.

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider.html)

The available methods is listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)